# SQL Server : compare values from two or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a query that compares data between two systems, System A and System B. In the final output table I should have `SystemA_Field`, `SystemB_Field` followed by `SystemA_Value`, `SystemB_Value` (see below).

This compares the values from the two systems along with the name of the columns of the two systems.

In other words, the columns have to be in the rows along with the column values.

[image]

Comment: do all tables have comparable ID fields?  Or are you using strictly the ordinal position of the columns to compare them?  Even so, you'll need to map the table names across systems if they differ.

Comment: If you do not have a field to link these tables it will be cartesian product of two tables which will produce useless results.

Comment: @Beth yes, all tables have comparable columns.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin sa.ContractNo = sb.ContractNumber the two tables have that in common

Comment: Does Table with Address have an ID?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin no it does not.

Comment: Is it a "college homework"? There is no common sense.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the results from your inner query?

```
     SELECT     
         ContractType, 
         LeaseType,
         ContractNo,  
         ContractNumber
     FROM         
         TableOne INNER JOIN 
         TableA ON 
         ContractNo = ContractNumber
     WHERE     
         ContractNo = 101
```

Comment: Did you see the output table? The columns have to be in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to output ContractNo & ContractNumber, because they have to ALWAYS match:

```
SELECT t1.ContractNo, t2.ContractNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.ContractType != t2.LeaseType THEN 'ContractType' 
    WHEN t1.[Address] != t2.AddressMain THEN 'Address' 
    ELSE 'N/A' END as SystemA_Field,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.ContractType != t2.LeaseType THEN 'LeaseType' 
    WHEN t1.[Address] != t2.AddressMain THEN 'AddressMain' 
    ELSE 'N/A' END as SystemB_Field,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.ContractType != t2.LeaseType THEN CAST(ContractType as VARCHAR)
    WHEN t1.[Address] != t2.AddressMain THEN CAST(Address as VARCHAR)
    ELSE 'N/A' END as SystemA_Value,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.ContractType != t2.LeaseType THEN CAST(LeaseType as VARCHAR)
    WHEN t1.[Address] != t2.AddressMain THEN CAST(AddressMain as VARCHAR)
    ELSE 'N/A' END as SystemB_Value
FROM Table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.ContractNo = t2.ContractNumber
WHERE t1.ContractType != t2.LeaseType
OR t1.[Address] != t2.AddressMain
```

BTW have you looked at Redgate's SQL Compare?
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-sdk/

Comment: This does not work. Lets say I want to add address and city as well.

Comment: I've changed the query to accommodate the second field.

Comment: Slava, ContractNo & ContractNumber has to be in the output since the user wants to see the comparison of the two fields.

Comment: It is very easy to add them.

Comment: Slava thanks for taking your time. But if I add t1.ContractNo to the select it adds a new column. t1.ContractNo has to be in the SystemA_Field and its value in SystemA_Value. I tried to add it to the case statement and it does not work.

Comment: Don't you want to know what is the ContractNo for different ContractType's or addresses? Why do you want to report lines when ContractNo's are the same?

Comment: This query is to report discrepancies. Since the data come from two systems there may data where there are not the same. So in other words all column names from SystemA tables should go in the SystemA_Field and all values should go in SystemA_Value. Same for SystemB.

Comment: If you need to report discrepancies you do not want to report situations when ContractNo's are the same. And when you report discrepancies for other fields you need ContractNo to identify these fields.

Comment: Slava. I am getting duplicate addresses for the address field in SystemA_Value and SystemB_Value. Anyways around this?

Comment: I do not see your data and I do not understand exact business requirements.